# Recognize character inside div and add class javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to recognize character inside div and add to all the matches class.

Example :

```
> Kapetown > China Town >London > Washington
```

I want to recognize the character `>` and give all of them class

I tried to do this

```
if (sign.indexOf("$") >= 0) {
 //remove the sign
}
```

Comment: so you want to replace all the `>` in `> Kapetown > China Town >London > Washington` with `$` in your div?

Comment: what's `> Kapetown > China Town >London > Washington`, XPath ?

Comment: @NickParsons I want to add to each ">" symbol classs

Comment: you can't give a class to an individual character. You'd have to wrap it in an inline element (typically a `<span>`) first

Comment: @RobinZigmond We cant run a javascript foreach that recognize all ">" inside div?

Comment: Of course you can - you can get the html content as a string and then use normal string methods on that. I was just pointing out that in order to give a class to something, it has to be an element, not just raw text - so you have to wrap the `>` in a `<span></span>` as part of what you're doing

Comment: I cant give him a class or id I can give the full text. @RobinZigmond

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you have before running script and what you want to get. I think it's not really clear for everybody

Answer (score 2):

Here is a trick you can use:

```
var a = '> Kapetown > China Town >London > Washington' //get the text from document here
a = a.split('>');
a = a.join('<span class="myClass">></span>');
```

Now you can replace "a" in your document.

This is just a trick you can use in your case. Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

> I assume that there is only text inside the targeted **div**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // get the target element
  var breadcrumbs = $('#breadcrumbs')
  // get all text of that element. Note: this will remove all
  // HTML tag and get only the text
  var str = breadcrumbs.text()
  // a regEx to find all occurrences of ">" sign
  // and wrap them with span.myClass
  var strHtml = str.replace(/\>/g, "<span class='myClass'>&gt;</span>");
  // push the replaced string back to the targeted element
  breadcrumbs.html(strHtml)
})
```

```css
.myClass {
  color: red;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="breadcrumbs">> Kapetown > China Town >London > Washington</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, then you have a particular HTML like so:

```
<div id="abc">
  > Capetown > China > London > Washington
</div>
```

and you want it to be lets say something like this:

```
<div id="abc">
      <span class="some-class">&gt;</span> Capetown <span class="some-class">&gt;</span> China <span class="some-class">&gt;</span> London <span class="some-class">&gt;</span> Washington
</div>
```

Then by vanilla javascript you could achieve this via Regex. Here is how I would do it if the HTML was like the example I proposed:

```
let content = document.getElementById('abc').textContent.replace(/>/g, '<span class="some-class">&gt;</span>');
document.getElementById('abc').innerHTML = content;
```

1. What I am doing here is that with `document.getElementById('abc').textContent`, I am getting the text content that is inside `<div id="abc">...</div>` and I am storing this text content in a mutable variable `content`.
2. Then I used the `String.prototype.replace` method of JavaScript to replace the required character (in our case it is the ">" character). The `String.prototype.replace` method accepts two parameters: a pattern and the replacement string. [read about the replace method here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
3. The character I want to select is ">". So using Regex the pattern I want to match is `/>/`. Now just using this expression will only match the first instance of ">". So I give it a global parameter to match all occurrences of ">" by `/>/g`.
4. Now we want to give it a class. So I decide to use the inline HTML element `<span>` to avoid any changes in the DOM layout. Now for the replacement substring, I use `<span class="some-class">&gt;</span>`. The `&gt;` is the HTML code for the ">" sign. Lets include these two parameters in our `String.prototype.replace` method as `content.replace(/>/g, '<span class="some-class">&gt;</span>');`
5. When executed, the variable `content` now contains our required character with a class. Next, I replaced the content of `<div id="abc">...</div>` by the `content` variable with `document.getElementById('abc').innerHTML = content;`. I used the `.innerHTML` property because we have included some HTML in our replacement string.

If this is what you wanted then hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

use can use `{'>'}` for react

example:

```
 <div className='row'>
   {route[0]} {'>'} {route[1]} {'>'} {route[2]}
 </div>
```

where `route = ["home","products","productID"];`